# KafkaProducer Connection refused

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I trying to send some data to kafka, but when i run my code i got

```
13:20:17.688 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] 
DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Node -1 disconnected.
13:20:17.784 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request
13:20:17.784 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node -1 at kafkaAdress:2181.
13:20:18.781 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - Connection with kafkaAdress/addressId disconnected
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:54)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:72)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:274)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:256)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:216)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:128)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Code:

```
    String topic = "TST";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "kafkaAdress:2181");
    props.put("key.serializer",      "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, "TestMessage"));    
    producer.close();
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I use kafka 0.9.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Kafka 0.9 the producer API no longer uses Zookeeper.

The property bootstrap.servers should contain a list of brokers for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster.

2181 is the zookeeper port. The default port for a broker is 9092.

Comment: Ok, i changed my bootsrap.servers properties to my brokers list. The error was'n appear but i stil not sending any data

Comment: Messages are sent asynchronously. you should try to add a callback to the send method to log the either the returned exception or the offset attached to each message.

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistake on your configuration, bootstrap.server is the Kafka broker's address, not zookeeper. Producer always use the broker's address to publish messages.